# Probability of integral being greater than a number

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I am very new to this.
Consider the continuous time stochastic process
$X(t)= Acos(\alpha t)+  Bsin(\alpha t) ,  t>0$ where the frequency  $\alpha$ is a positive constant that is known. $A, B $ are independent, normally distributed random variables with means 0 and variances 1.
I want to compute the probability $P(\int_{0}^{2\pi/\alpha}X^2(t)dt>c)$ for a constant $c$

Clearly $X^2(t)= A^2cos^2(\alpha t)+B^2sin^2(\alpha t)+2ABsin(\alpha t)cos(\alpha t)$
I can also split the terms and integrate using something like Wolfram but the pieces are messy. Also I want to find that the probability of the integral is greater than c. Does this mean a double integral is involved? Not sure what to do from there or how to use the information given about the means and variances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since $\cos ^{2} {\theta}=\frac 1  2 (1+\cos (2 \theta))$ we get $$\int_0^{2\pi /\alpha} \cos ^{2}(\alpha t)dt=\frac1 2\int_0^{2\pi /\alpha} [1+\cos(2\alpha t)]dt=\frac {\pi} {\alpha}.$$ Similarly compute the other two terms using the idenitities $\sin ^{2} {\theta}=\frac 1  2 (1-\cos (2 \theta))$ and $\sin \theta \cos \theta=\frac 1 2 \sin (2 \theta)$.

Comment: Ok. So the integral evaluates to $\frac{\pi}{\alpha}(A^2+B^2)$. What does it mean to calculate the probability that this quantity is greater than some constant c

Comment: @Jama See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution

Comment: So am I calculating $F(2\pi/\alpha)- F(0,2)$?

Comment: The answer is $1-F(\frac {c \alpha} {\pi})$ where $F$ is chi-square distribution with $2$ degrees of freedom. @Jama

Comment: $F$ is the distribution of $A^{2}+B^{2}$. I have just used the definition of distribution function to write $P(\frac {\pi} {\alpha} (A^{2}+B^{2}) >c)$ as $1-F(\frac  {c\alpha} {\pi})$.